# Accepting a first argument of type for (InserOnSubmit Method)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am working on MVC project, i am doing simple data insertion to database table(sqlserver),
Here i am using Linq to sql (.dbml extension) and 
Here is the Linq query

```
var dataContext = new CandidatedContext();
dataContext.Candidates.InsertOnSubmit(employees);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

But it's showing error at InsertOnSubmit and SubmitChanges(could not found)

When I Google I found some solution like

1. should add refrence  of (using System.Data.Linq;) fr this i added refrence
2. Guides must be an object that doesn't implement the InsertOnSubmit method. 
   for 2nd is it correct because I had uniqueidentifier in my database,
   But if I tried with example table which is having primary key with id. than also it's not working.
3. InsertOnSubmit is a Linq-to-SQL method and not in the Entity Framework. Here mine id (.dbml)
   But still i am getting error

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use 
TableName object=new Tablename();
object.field1=value;
object.field2=value;
db.TableName.AddObject(object);
```

Comment: ok thankyou for solution,here i wnat to navigate one controller to antoher controller action using    RedirectToAction; how?

Comment: OtherParam is nothing but the other parameter that your controller is expecting for example if your controller is public ActionResult userAccount(int id=1,string otherParam) so otherParam is what your controller is expecting in form of string if your controller requires one param then pass 1 param..And please up my comment if i solved your problem ...i am also a newbie

Comment: sorry my problem is, i didn't understand where to write RedirectToAction method

Comment: 'm trying to navigate from the account controller to the edit view in the profile controller.RedirectToAction("Edit", "Profile", new {id = 1, otherParam = "foo"});  here but where to write this function? while click the actionlik this method should be raise how?